# What is the flags in GOCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET used for

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf, flags

I'm trying to build a GDB. The Makefile generated by configure contains a flags called "GOCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET". Could anyone tell me what the "GOCFLAGS" is used for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its makefile builtin-variables for the Go programming language which I understand that GCC supports.  You may find more info [here.](http://blog.golang.org/2012/07/gccgo-in-gcc-471.html)